# solution of $h(x,x^2)h(y,y^2)=g(x+y,x^2+y^2)$

Tags: real-analysis

$ h:R^{N+1} \to [0 , \infty)$ ,  $ h $ is measurable

$ g:R^{N+1} \to [0 , \infty)$ ,  $ g $ is measurable

$x,y \in  R^N$

$$h (x, x^2) h (y, y^2)= g (x+y, x^2+y^2)$$

Where $x^2$ is the dot product $x.x=|x|^2$

(1) Can it be shown that $h(0,0) \neq 0$

(2). what is the solution of  **1** by only assuming $h$ is measurable ?

**Comment** :

I was only able to show $h(x,x^2)=Ae^{b.x+cx^2}$  under  2 conditions:

1. $h$ is finite and measurable
2. $h(x,x^2) >0 \text{ whenever $|x-a|^2<r^2$}$

where ,$b,a \in R^N, r>0,c \in R$ and $A=e^{h(0,0)}$

clearly $h(a,a^2) > 0$

$h(x+a,|x+a|^2)h(a,a^2)=g(x+2a,|x+a|^2+a^2)$

$h(y+a,|y+a|^2)h(a,a^2)=g(y+2a,|y+a|^2+a^2)$

$h(x+a,|x+a|^2)h(y+a,|y+a|^2)h^2(a,a^2)=g(x+2a,|x+a|^2+a^2)g(y+2a,|y+a|^2+a^2)$

$h^2(a,a^2)g(x+y+2a,|x+a|^2+|y+a|^2)=g(x+2a,|x+a|^2+a^2)g(y+2a,|y+a|^2+a^2)$

let $f(x,x^2)=\frac{g(x+2a,|x+a|^2+a^2)}{h(a,a^2)}=\frac{g(x+2a,x^2+2x\cdot a + 2a^2)}{h(a,a^2)}$

clearly $f(0,0)=\frac{g(2a,2a^2)}{h(a,a^2)}=h(a,a^2)>0$

Also clearly $f(x,x^2)f(y,y^2)=g(x+y+2a,x^2+y^2+2a^2+2a\cdot (x+y))$

Let $G(x+y,x^2+y^2)=g(x+y+2a,x^2+y^2+2a^2+2a\cdot (x+y))$

$$\text{ Therefore $f(x,x^2)f(y,y^2)=G(x+y,x^2+y^2)$ } $$

Note $$f(x,x^2)=h(x+a,|x+a|^2)$$

$$f (x, x^2) f (y, y^2)= G (x+y, x^2+y^2) \tag{1}$$

pluging $y=0$ in **1** :$f(x,x^2)f(0,0)=G(x,x^2)$, also $f(y,y^2)f(0,0)=G(y,y^2)$

and multiply the two equations and use **1**  to obtain **2**

$$f^2(0,0)G(x+y,x^2+y^2)=G(x,x^2)G(y,y^2) \tag{2}$$

use **1** to obtain this two equations

$$G(0,2x^2)=f(x,x^2)f(-x,x^2) \tag{3}$$

$$G(0,2y^2)=f(y,y^2)f(-y,y^2) \tag{4}$$

for $x.y=0 $ and $x^2=y^2$,
$$G(0,2x^2)G(0,2y^2)=f(x,x^2)f(-y,y^2)f(y,y^2)f(-x,x^2)=G(x-y,x^2+y^2)G(y-x,x^2+y^2)$$

$$G(x-y,x^2+y^2)G(y-x,x^2+y^2)=f^2(0,0)f(x-y,x^2+y^2)f(y-x,x^2+y^2)=f^2(0,0)G(0,2x^2+2y^2)$$

So  $G(0,2y^2)G(0,2x^2)=f^2(0,0)G(0,2x^2+2y^2) \tag{5}$

Therefore plugging $x^2=y^2$ into above to get :$$G^2(0,2x^2)=f^2(0,0)G(0,4x^2)\tag{6}$$

Applying 6 recursively,

$$G^{2^{n+1}}(0,\frac{y^2}{2^{n+1}})=f^{2n+2}(0,0)G(0,y^2) \text{ for every $n \in N$} \tag{7}$$

under condition 2, $f(0,0)\neq 0$, then it can be shown $f>0$ everywhere as done below :

from **1**  , $f^2(0,0)G(x+y,x^2+y^2)=G(x,x^2)G(y,y^2)$

$f^2(0,0)G(0,2x^2)=G(x,x^2)G(-x,x^2)$

from **7**

$$f^2(0,0)G(0,2x^2)=\frac{f^2(0,0)G^{2^{n+1}}(0,\frac{2x^2}{2^{n+1}})}{f^{2n+2}(0,0)}$$

$$\frac{f^2(0,0)G^{2^{n+1}}(0,\frac{2x^2}{2^{n+1}})}{f^{2n+2}(0,0)}=G(x,x^2)G(-x,x^2)$$

By condition 2 $\lim_{n \to \infty}G(0,\frac{2x^2}{2^{n+1}})>0$

for large $n$ the left hand side of the above equation is greater than zero, so $G(x,x^2)>0$ implying $f(x,x^2)>0$

$logf(x,x^2)+logf(y,y^2)=logG(x+y,x^2+y^2)$  and can easily be converted into cauchy functional equation

$f_1(x,x^2)=logf(x,x^2)-logf(0,0)$, so $f_1(0,0)=0$

$G_1(x,x^2)=logG(x,x^2)-2logf(0,0)=logG(x,x^2)-logG(0,0)$, so $G_1(0,0)=0$

$f_1(x,x^2)+f_1(y,y^2)=G_1(x+y,x^2+y^2)$

plugging $y=0$ into above to get $f_1(x,x^2)=G_1(x,x^2)$

Now $f_1(x,x^2)+f_1(y,y^2)=f_1(x+y,x^2+y^2)$

let $n$ be number of components of $x$ ,for $i \in N$ let the ith components of $x,y$ be $x_i,y_i$ respectively

That is to say if $x= \langle a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n \rangle $

$x_i= \langle 0, a_i,0,0,0, \ldots, 0\rangle $
and so on

for $x.y=0$, $\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i=0$

$f_1(x,x^2)=\sum_{i=1}^nf_1(x_i,x_i^2)$

$f_1(y,y^2)=\sum_{i=1}^nf_1(y_i,y_i^2)$

$f_1(x+y,x^2+y^2)=\sum_{i=1}^nf_1(x_i,x_i^2)+\sum_{i=1}^nf_1(y_i,y_i^2)$

$f_1(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i+y_i),\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i^2+y_i^2))=\sum_{i=1}^nf_1(x_i+y_i,x_i^2+y_i^2)$

let $u_i=x_i+y_i,v_i=x_i^2+y_i^2$

$u_i,v_i$ can be taken as independent variables under the condition$u_i^2 \le 2v_i$

$f_1(\sum_{i=1}^nu_i,\sum_{i=1}^nv_i)=\sum_{i=1}^nf_1(u_i,v_i)$

now we can swap two variables for example $v_1$ and $v_2$

we have $f_1(u_1,v_1)+f_1(u_2,v_2)=f_1(u_1,v_2)+f_1(u_2,v_1)$ provided that that both $u_1^2\le 2v_1,u_1^2 \le 2v_2,u_2^2\le 2v_1,u_2^2 \le 2v_2,$

now taking $u_2=0$ and $v_2$ is constant ie $v_2=v_o$

$f_1(u_1,v_1)=f_1(u_1,v_o)-f_1(0,v_o)+f_1(0,v_1)$

define $p(u_1)=f_1(u_1,v_o)-f_1(0,v_o)$, $\rho(v_1)=f_1(0,v_1)$

$f_1(u_1,v_1)=p(u_1)+f_1(0,v_1)$

now we can set $u_1=x_1,v_1=x_1^2$ because the inequality $u_1^2\le 2v_1$ is still satisfied

To get $f_1(x_1,x_1^2)=p(x_1)+\rho (x_1^2)$

Noting that $ G(0,2y^2)G(0,2x^2)=f^2(0,0)G(0,2x^2+2y^2)$ as derived above

it implies that for $d,c \ge 0,G(0,d)G(0,c)=f^2(0,0)G(0,d+c)$

$logG(0,d)+logG(0,c)=2logf(0,0)+logG(0,d+c)$

Noting $logG(0,0)=2logf(0,0)$

$logG_1(0,d)=logG(0,d)-logG(0,0)$

$logG_1(0,d)+logG_1(0,c)=logG_1(0,d+c)$

but $f_1(0,d)=G_1(0,d)$

so $\rho (x_1^2)+\rho (y_1^2)=\rho (x_1^2+y_1^2)$, which is Cauchy functional equation with solution $\rho (x_1^2)=c_1x_1^2$

because $\rho (x^2)+\rho (y^2)=\rho (x^2+y^2)$, $c_i=c$ for all $i \in N$

$f_1(x_1,x_1^2)=p(x_1)+cx_1^2$

$f_1(x_1+y_1,x_1^2+y_1^2)=f_1(x_1,x_1^2)+f_1(y_1,y_1^2)$

$p(x_1+y_1)+\rho(x_1^2+y_1^2)=p(x_1)+p(y_1)+\rho(x_1^2)+\rho(y_1^2)$

This means $p(x_1)+p(y_1)=p(x_1+y_1)$ which is also Cauchy functional equation with solution $p (x_1)=b_1x_1$

Therefore $f_1(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^nb_ix_i+c\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2=b.x+cx^2$

And $f(x,x^2)= Ae^{b.x+cx^2}$ Where $A=e^{f(0,0)}$

Comment: $f(x,x^2)$ makes no sense, both considering the domain of $f$ and the multiplication $x^2$.

Comment: @I was suspended for talking , I didnt get you.

Comment: Even if $x^2 = |x|^2$ (which is nonstandard), if $f$ is defined on $\Bbb R^N$ then $(x,x^2)\in \Bbb R^{N+1}$, so $f(x,x^2)$ is not defined.

Comment: I agree with @Iwassuspendedfortalking, I can't make out what the question is.

Comment: @Iwassuspendedfortalking i doubt u were suspended just for talking

Comment: @I was suspended for talking , correction made

Comment: @mathworker21 I was just telling what makes frogs gay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excluding the trivial case for $h=0$ ae, then it must be that $h$ is positive on some set of positive
measure

The functional equation can be coverted to

$$f (x, x^2) f (y, y^2)= G (x+y, x^2+y^2) \text{with $f(0,0)>0$} \tag{1}$$

using equation 5 :$G(0,2y^2)G(0,2x^2)=f^2(0,0)G(0,2x^2+2y^2) \tag{5}$

$G(0,d)G(0,c)=f^2(0,0)G(0,d+c) $, where $d,c \ge 0$

according to equation above if $d>0$ and $G(0,d) >0$, then $G(0,c)>0$ for all $c>0$

using equation 1 we have $f(0,0)f(x+y, x^2+y^2)=f(x, x^2) f (y, y^2)$, let $x.y=0$
using equation 1 we have $f(0,0)f(s+z, s^2+z^2)=f(s, s^2) f (z, z^2)$, let $s.z=0$

combining the two equations and using 1: $f(0,0)f(x+y+s+z, x^2+y^2+s^2+z^2)=f(x+s, x^2+s^2)f(y+z, y^2+z^2)$

now let $u=x+s,v=y+z,w=x^2+s^2,t=y^2+z^2$

we have $$f(0,0)f(u+v, w+t)=f(u, w)f(v,t)$$

$u,v,w,t$ can be taken as independent variables under the condition:

$u^2 \le 2w$ ,$v^2 \le 2t$

take $v=0$ , $t=\frac{x^2}{2}$,$u=x$ , $w=\frac{x^2}{2}$

we have $$f(0,0)f(x, x^2)=f(x, \frac{x^2}{2})f(0,\frac{x^2}{2})$$

because there is a point $d\neq 0$,$f(d, d^2)>0$, $f(0,0)f(0,\frac{d^2}{2})=G(0,\frac{d^2}{2})>0$

$f(x,x^2)f(-x,x^2)=G(0,2x^2)>0$ implies $f(x,x^2)>0$ everywhere

and equation $1$ can be converted to Cauchy functional equation as done in my comment

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

This answer does not contain a strict proof, only some details of the full solution.

Let
$$F(x) = f(x,x^2),\quad G(x,y)=H\left(\dfrac{1+i}2x+\dfrac{1-i}2y,\dfrac{1-i}2x +\dfrac{1+i}2y\right)\tag1$$
then
$$F(x)F(y) = H(x+y,xy).\tag2$$

$\color{brown}{\mathbf{Case\ 1.\ F(x)\ is\ an\ exponent\ of\ a\ power.}}$

Let $n\ge 0.$
$$F(x) = e^{x^n},\tag3$$
then
$$\ln(F(x)F(y)) = x^n+y^n = S_n(x+y,xy),$$
where, in accordance with Littlewood and Cardogan formulas for [Symmetric Polynomials](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SymmetricPolynomial.html),
$$S_n(u,v) = \begin{vmatrix}
u  & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
2v & u & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0  & v & u & 1 & \dots & 0 \\
0  & 0 & v & u & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & u \\
\end{vmatrix}.\tag4$$

Therefore, the pair of functions 
\begin{cases}
F_n(x) = e^{x^n}\\
H_n(x,y) = e^{S_n(x,y)}\tag5
\end{cases}
presents the solution of $(2)$ in the case $(3).$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Common case.}}$

From $(2),(3),(5)$ should that the pair of the functions
\begin{cases}
F(\vec c,x) = A\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty (F_n(x))^{c_n}(F_n(\,^1/_x))^{c_{-n}}\\
H(\vec c,x,y) = A^2\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty (H_n(x,y))^{c_n}(H_n(\,^x/_y,\,^1/_y))^{c_{-n}},
\end{cases}
or
\begin{cases}
F(\vec c,x) = Ae^{^{\Large\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (c_nx^n+c_{-n}x^{-n})}}\\
H(\vec c,x,y) = A^2e^{^{\Large\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (c_nS_n(x,y)+c_{-n}S_n(\,^x/_y,\,^1/_y))}},\tag6
\end{cases}
presents the solutions of $(2)$ in the common case.

Finally, solutions of the functional equation
$$f(x,x^2)f(y,y^2) = G(x+y,x^2+y^2)$$
can be expressed in the form of
\begin{cases}
f(x,y) = F(\vec c, \varphi(x,y))\\
G(x,y) = H\left(\vec c,\dfrac{1+i}2x+\dfrac{1-i}2y,\dfrac{1-i}2x +\dfrac{1+i}2y\Large\mathstrut\right),\tag7
\end{cases}
where $\varphi(x,y)$ is the arbitrary function such that
$$\varphi(x,x^2) = x\tag8$$
(examples: $\varphi(x,y) = x,\quad \varphi(x,y) = \sqrt[3]{xy},\quad\varphi(x,y) = x^2+x-y,\quad$ etc.)

Comment: Thanks what if $f$ can take zero values, logarithms how ?

Comment: @ibnAbu As a rule, multiplicative models exclude this variant. On the other hand, the trivial solution $f=G=0$ had been missed. And what about accept?